# R Using Regex to find a word after a pattern

Tags: r, regex, xml, rcurl

I'm grabbing the following page and storing it in R with the following code:

```
gQuery <- getURL("https://www.google.com/#q=mcdimalds")
```

Within this, there's the following snippet of code

`Showing results for</span> <a class="spell" href="/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS743US743&amp;q=mcdonalds&amp;spell=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwj9koqPx_TTAhUKLSYKHRWfDlYQvwUIIygA"><b><i>mcdonalds</i></b></a>`

Everything other than "showing results for" and the italics tags encasing the desired name for extraction are subject to change from query to query.

What I want to do is extract the `mcdonalds` out of this string using regex that occurs here: `<b><i>mcdonalds</i>` aka the second instance of `mcdonalds`. However, I'm not too sure how to write the regex to do so.

Any help accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated. As always, please let me know if any additional information should be added to clarify the question.

Comment: There are 2 instances of `mcdonalds` which one do you want to extract? I.e. - do you want to extract whatever is in between `<i>` and `</i>` or whatever is after `q=`?

Comment: Use HTML tools to deal with HTML, not regex. To grab the displayed text, `library(rvest); h <- '<a class="spell" href="/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS743US743&amp;q=mcdonalds&amp;spell=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwj9koqPx_TTAhUKLSYKHRWfDlYQvwUIIygA"><b><i>mcdonalds</i></b></a>'; h %>% read_html() %>% html_node('a') %>% html_text()`. To pull it out of the query, `h %>% read_html() %>% html_node('a') %>% html_attr('href') %>% httr::parse_url() %>% .$query %>% .$q` All that said, I'm sure Google would rather you use their APIs than scrape them.

Comment: @alistaire I get where you're coming from, but is there a way to do this from storing the entire HTML page and not just taking the snippet? Everything other than "showing results for" and the italics tags encasing the target name are subject to change from query to query.

Comment: @MikeH. OP updated to specify. It would be between `<i>` and `</i>`

Comment: Yep, time to learn [CSS selectors](http://flukeout.github.io/)

Comment: Also, check out their terms and conditions. They built their APIs so people won't scrape them; further, using an API instead would avoid your current hassle.

Comment: @alistaire do you know of an API that I could use? From what I could find, Google discontinued their predictive API and their search query API isn't available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144390/discussion-between-jonathan-rauscher-and-alistaire).

Comment: if the get variable q=mcdonalds is the same as the string enclosed in <i></i>, You could just explode the string with & as delimiter (maybe first unquote/transform html symbols into UTF8), then remove 'q=' using a substring. Add the italics tags to the string and you're done.